# What is a "safety variable"?

Tags: algorithm, ranking, social-media

I was just reading an article about [different ranking algorithms](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/reddit-stumbleupon-delicious-and-hacker-news-algorithms-exposed).  One thing I'm a bit confused about is stumbleupon's algoritm:

> (Initial stumbler audience / # domain)
>   + ((% stumbler audience / # domain) + organic bonus – nonfriend) – (%
>   stumbler audience + organic bonus) + N
>
> N is a "safety variable" so that the
>   assumed algorithm is flexible. It
>   represents a random number.

Could someone explain the purpose of N to me?  I don't understand how it's making the algorithm more flexible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It helps the results degrade at an unpredictable rate. If you've ever stumbled for a couple of hours you'll likely have noticed a serious decline in the quality and relevance of each stumble as you start scraping the bottom of the barrel.

Without the random variable the results would degrade in a very predictable rate. The link you were most likely to love would be first and each subsequent link would likely appeal a little less to you. The variable attempts to negate this somewhat.

It's one of the many clever ways stumbleupon is [designed to be addictive](http://serendip.brynmawr.edu/bb/neuro/neuro05/web1/isiddiqui.html):

> The results were unanimous in
>   the fact that when one performed an
>   action over and over again, and was
>   given a reward randomly, dopamine
>   levels rose. If the reward was given
>   consistently, i.e. every four time the
>   action was performed, the dopamine
>   levels remained constant

Answer (score 5):

By introducing N you ensure that stuff that is not rated very often yet gets shuffled to the top occassionally (if N turns out high). I guess this ensures that everything gets seen at least a few times initially, and thus gets a few shots at obtaining more stumbles (or whatever they're called).
Basically just slight randomization of new stuff to remove top-spot bias.

That is my guess anyway.